# Forming multiple columns from data in a perticular column based on condition in PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark daframe like

```
item_id   attribute_id  attribute_value
1001      color          blue
1001      shape          rectangular
1001      material       copper
1002      color          black
1002      material       copper
1003      color          grey
```

I Want Resultant dataframe to match below

```
item_id   color    shape        meterial 
1001      blue     rectangular  copper
1002      black    null         copper
1003      grey     null         null
```

I am trying achieve this in PySpark but not sure about the syntax, Any Hints? Note: Any pointers in PySpark or spark sql is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation you are looking for is [`pivot`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot.html). You should group the dataframe by `item_id` then `pivot` based on `attribute_id` and finally choose the first value of `attribute_value`.

```py
data = [(1001, "color", "blue",),
        (1001, "shape", "rectangular",),
        (1001, "material", "copper",),
        (1002, "color", "black",),
        (1002, "material", "copper",),
        (1003, "color", "grey",), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("item_id", "attribute_id", "attribute_value",))

df.groupBy("item_id").pivot("attribute_id").agg(F.first("attribute_value")).show()

"""
+-------+-----+--------+-----------+
|item_id|color|material|      shape|
+-------+-----+--------+-----------+
|   1001| blue|  copper|rectangular|
|   1002|black|  copper|       null|
|   1003| grey|    null|       null|
+-------+-----+--------+-----------+
"""
```